# How to generate un-similar color palettes?

Tags: html, css, colors

I'm going to draw a bunch of areas on the map. Each area should be of different color, preferably clearly different from the others. Of course, as the number of areas grows, I'm ducked. But until then I wonder where I could find or how I could generate a set of, say 15 colors that are "vastly" apart.

The first few were easy, because I used the defaults from Bootstrap:

- blue
- yellow
- red
- green
- pink

But I can't stop wondering if there's a trick, tool or algorithm for generating a *next, deviating color*.

Googling gave me ways to generate similar schemas or colors that go well together. That's not what I'm looking for, though. Also, I discovered that there's much, muuuuch more to colors than mixing RGB, so I feel like a total looser noob.

Comment: How about shooting for evenly spaced colors on the hue spectrum? In css, colors can be defined with `hsl()` where `h` is the hue in degrees.

Comment: Pseudocode: `h=0; color="hsl("+h+", 70%, 70%)"; h+=56; h%=360;`

Comment: @Sheraff That's actually kind of great for my little issue. Also - is your name inherited from a long-necked animal? It sounds so...

Comment: 2@RokoC.Buljan Yupp, that's great. Now, I'll need to work out how to generate that in TypeScript to create an array of shades. Both yours and Sheraff's are quite helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should indeed use the `hsl` 360 degrees to generate a well spread color spectrum. To have something like that in typescript/js you could do:

```
const length = 15;
const colors = Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => `hsl(${360 / length * i}, 50%, 50%)`);
```

Here you can see a working example:

[stack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f7d9fc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

Result:

[image]

Comment: This was great hint. I went to bed and was planning to dig into the details in the morning. Then - tada! your answer comes along. This is entirely satisfactory and spot on what I needed. One thing I noticed, though, is that the map is covered by opaque colors when I provide HSL based values (whereas it previously had certain degree of transparency when I sent in hexa-RGB). I never specified any transparency for RGB neither assuming that the map converts that for me in each case. However, it appears that when I style using HSL, the transparency is eliminated. Hints on that?

Comment: @KonradViltersten you can use `hsla` if you want transparency, where a is alpha. So ``hsla(${360 / length * i}, 50%, 50%, 0.5)`` to have it semi opaque. About the hexa-rgb. If you have 6 characters (#F0F0F0), there is no transparency, if you have 8 characters (#F0F0F0F0), the last two define the transparency

Comment: This is not Typescript.

Comment: @Sheraff It's not? Darn, then I should rethink my career :)

Comment: I'm just saying, this is vanilla JS. There's no reason to say it's typescript specifically. I'm so used to seeing new developers not understanding how jquery and js relate to each other. I don't think we should promote the same kind of confusion with typescript now.

Comment: @Sheraff well, javascript is typescript :) that's the difference. In the comment the OP asked for a typescript solution, so that's why I mentioned it. Nevertheless the code provided also compiles in the strict mode from typescript, meaning that all typings are accounted for. 

Anyways, I understand what you mean, and I've updated my answer

Comment: @Sheraff While I understand your worry for the outcome of ignorant people's assumptions and whole-heart'ly support the cause for mentioning that, I wonder if you can suggest a more TS-specific approach to this matter. I mean that using JS when there's a better TS way is bad, regardless if it works or not in Angular. Amen to that. However, using JS when there's nothing else corresponding to it in TS is, n fact, the only possible approach. Hence, proper choice in TS-terms. So, do you have a hint on how to TS'fy the suggested solution or is it already maximally TS'y as is?